# Bad File descriptor error while saving re sized image using PIL In Django

Tags: python, django

I am very new in Django.Recently i am developing a website related to image.I have a thumbnail page where the images will be shown.Now i want to re size images aspect there ratio.Thats why i have write the following code in My **imageThumbnail** view,

```
def imageThumbnail(request,template = 'base.html',page_template = 'photo/showphoto.html'):
    photo_list = Photo.objects.order_by('-uploaded_time')
    basewidth = 300
    for photo_ratio in photo_list:
        img =Image.open(photo_ratio.photo)
        wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        resized_img=img.save(photo_ratio.photo)

    context = {}
    context.update({
      'photo_list': resized_img,
      'page_template': page_template,
    })

    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template

return render_to_response(template,context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here **Photo** is my model name.Now the problem is, i am facing an error which is something like that

```
 IOError at /showphoto/
 [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

which indicating the line where i have saved my resized image

```
resized_img=img.save(photo_ratio.photo)
```

Now my question is,whats wrong i have done in that line?In mention,i am using PIL(Python Image Library) and i have  imported the **PIL** and **Image** from PIL.Though I am very new in Django and Python,i can't figure it out whats going wrong there in my code.

**UPDATE**
The mistake i have made that i don't save those images in a directory or a temporary directory,thats why i have rewrite  my code as like this,

```
 def imageThumbnail(request,template = 'base.html',page_template = 'photo/showphoto.html'):

    import os
    SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR,os.pardir)
    PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

    photo_list = Photo.objects.order_by('-uploaded_time')
    basewidth = 300

    for photo_ratio in photo_list:
        img =Image.open(photo_ratio.photo)
        wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        temp_images =os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'media',photo_ratio.photo)

        resized_img=img.save(temp_images)
```

but now i am facing the error,

```
 AttributeError at /showphoto/
'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

at

```
temp_images =os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'media',photo_ratio.photo)
```

any idea what is going on?

Comment: something doesn't add up - you use the `photo_ratio` and `img` variable outside of the loop. do you intentionally only want to perform these actions after the last iteration? This might also produce an exception because you refer to these variables also when the loop won't iterate at all

Comment: if i place the photo_ratio and img variable inside the loop,same error is raising.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't answering the question, just wanted to understand what's going on.. that's why I commented and didn't answer.. :)

Comment: BTW - I think that when you provide a file object to the `save` method, you should also provide the format parameter.

Comment: I have added the format parameter too,but its still raising the same error.

Comment: OK, I think I got it, not posting it as an answer because I am not entirely sure. I think that the problem is that you send the "save" method the `photo_ratio.photo` variable which is NOT a File or Image instance, it is an ImageField instance which in turn is just a Field object, not implementing the `read`,`seek` and other methods required according to PIL's documentation. You should instead, use `photo_ratio.photo.save(<file_name>, ContentFile(img.read())`

Comment: What should replace the "ContentFile" ? is it a syntax? because now i am facing an exception saying "Global name ContentFile is not defined"

Comment: ContentFile is a type of object that resides in Django in `django.core.files.base.ContentFile`. But you can also use `File` instead (because you have a real file)

Comment: should i import 'File' from django.core.files.base ? cause now when i use the File,its showing the error that "Global name File is not defined"

Comment: Yes, you can import that one.

Comment: Now its showing an **Attribur error**.Its just showing only "read" as a **Attribute error**

Comment: is there any issue to save those resized image in a temp folder? @LauriElias

Comment: I have edited my post,can @LauriElias  suggest me what should i do,whats wrong i have made?i am really new in python and django and stuck with this problem and don't find any solution after a huge research and googling.

Comment: Try changing `img =Image.open(photo_ratio.photo)` to `img =Image.open(photo_ratio.photo.path)` and `temp_images =os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'media',photo_ratio.photo)` to `temp_images =os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'media',photo_ratio.photo.path)`. Try stuff line by line and see where it crashes, print out type(obj) to see what you're dealing with etc. You'll have a solution in a few minutes.

Comment: Also, I solved my EXIF problem by using Pillow instead of PIL, in case you'll need this next.

Comment: I have change my code according to your suggestion,now everything seems okay ,but,no images are showing in my thumbnail.